# How do I check the packages installed with make command?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

If a package is installed with make command long back, how to know now if someone deleted or it is still there?

For example, I can use "yum list" command to know all installed packages with yum, similarly we can use "rpm -qa" to know the packages installed with rpm, but how to know the packages installed with "make"?

Comment: Turn on and mind your compiler warnings! Try `gcc -Wall -Wextra ...`

Comment: Using `yum` does not work on all systems, not even all Linux systems unless the software installed by `make` took steps to register itself as being installed, there is no way to find out other than.manual inspection or ”try it and see what fails”.

Comment: `make` is just a specialized tool - basically a scripting language, not a paokage manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yum keeps a database, when you do the `yum list` command, yum is actually referencing the database.

The traditional "make install" doesn't typically update a database for future queries.  In addition, it can be altered by setting installation PREFIX variables, and can install a consistent set of files nearly anywhere.

This means that in general, the facility you want isn't there.  However, there are some tools that might help

`pkgconfig` is a tool that some bits of software use, to help developers identify libraries that are installed (if they were installed in a pkagconfig-compatible way) and with the installation, one can grab the compiler flags and loader flags using the `pkgconfig` tool.  This makes the building of future programs easier, but again, since it is optional you can't trust it to know about any installed program.

For a makefile only solution, I'd try to call the software, and if calling it fails, then assume the software isn't installed or the installation location is wrong.